# This question is based on normal to the ellipse

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

If the normal at $(4 \cos \alpha, 3 \sin \alpha)$ on the ellipse $9 x^2+16 y^2=144$ again intersects the ellipse at $(4 \cos \beta, 3 \sin \beta)$, then $\cos \beta=\cos \alpha\left(\frac{a-b \cos ^2 \alpha}{c-d \cos ^2 \alpha}\right)$ where $\mathrm{a}, \mathrm{b}, \mathrm{c}, \mathrm{d} \in \mathrm{N}$ and $\operatorname{GCD}(\mathrm{a}, \mathrm{b}, \mathrm{c}, \mathrm{d})=1 .(\alpha \neq \mathrm{n} \pi, \mathrm{n} \in \mathrm{I})$ we have to find ab,c,d.

I have written equation of normal to ellipse at first point.
Then substituted second point and got a relationbut stuck after that

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: how to find a, b, c, d

Comment: What equation did you get for the normal?  What did you get when you substituted?

Comment: the standard equation for ellipse

Answer (score 1):

Let $P = (x_1, y_1) = ( 4 \cos \alpha, 3 \sin \alpha ) $

The normal vector at $P$ is $ g = ( 3 \cos \alpha, 4 \sin \alpha)$

Therefore, the normal line at $P$ has the parametric equation

$ \ell(s) = P + s g = (4 \cos \alpha , 3 \sin \alpha) + s ( 3 \cos \alpha, 4 \sin \alpha) = ( (4 + 3 s) \cos \alpha , (3 + 4 s ) \sin \alpha )$

Substituting this into the equation of the ellipse, we get

$ 9 (4 + 3 s)^2 \cos^2 \alpha + 16 (3 + 4 s)^2 \sin^2 \alpha = 144 $

And this reduces to

$ s( 216  \cos^2 \alpha + 224  \sin^2 \alpha ) + s^2 ( 81 \cos^2 \alpha + 256 \sin^2 \alpha) = 0 $

Since $s\ne 0$ then

$s = - \dfrac{ 216 \cos^2 \alpha + 224 \sin^2 \alpha }{ 81 \cos^2 \alpha + 256 \sin^2 \alpha } $

Substitute this into the expression for $\ell(s)$, you get

$ Q = P + s g = ( (4 + 3 s ) \cos \alpha, (3 + 4 s ) \sin \alpha ) \\
= \dfrac{( (-324 \cos^2 \alpha + 352 \sin^2 \alpha) \cos \alpha , (-621 \cos^2 \alpha - 128 \sin^2 \alpha ) \sin \alpha ) }{81 \cos^2 \alpha + 256 \sin^2 \alpha }$

But $Q = ( 4 \cos \beta , 3 \sin \beta ) $

Therefore,

$ \cos \beta = \cos \alpha \left( \dfrac{ -81 \cos^2 \alpha + 88 \sin^2 \alpha }{81 \cos^2 \alpha + 256 \sin^2 \alpha }\right) $

Changing $\sin^2 \alpha$ into $1 - \cos^2 \alpha$, we get:

$ \cos \beta = \cos \alpha \left( \dfrac{ 88 - 169 \cos^2 \alpha}{256 - 175 \cos^2 \alpha} \right) $

Therefore, $a = 88 , b = 169, c = 256, d = 175 $